# Eclipse - How to "Change package declaration to ...." across an entire project

Tags: java, eclipse, package, packaging

I've just imported a large amount of source code into Eclipse and basically the package name is no longer valid (the code has been moved folders). Is there a way to select all the source code in the Package Explorer and hit a hotkey so that all package declarations are correctly resolved for me? I know you can do this with imports by selecting the source and hitting ctl-shift-o, but is also possible for the package declaration?

**Update:** *Refactoring the packages doesn't work as I don't want to change the name or location of the packages, I just need to adjust the package declaration in the Java source code.*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If the package declarations are no longer valid, then all such invalid declarations would appear in the `Problems` view in Eclipse. If you do not see this view, you can open it from Window-> Show View -> Other... -> Problems (under the General tab).

You can filter on problems in the Problems view and correct easily correctable ones, by choosing the `Quick fix` option in the context menu (available on a right-click). In your case you should see something similar to the screenshot posted below:

[image: Quick fix for incorrect packages]

Applying the quick fix options is trivial, as long as you know which one is correct - you would either have to change the package declaration in the class, or the location of the class itself. Unfortunately there is no option to fix the issue across multiple units at one go; you will have to apply the quick fix for every problem.

If you want to filter on problems of only this variety, consider configuring the Problems view to show all errors that have the text content "does not match the expected package" in the error text, as demonstrated in the following screenshots:

[image: Configure Problem Contents]

[image: Eclipse Configure Package Problems]

Comment: Great response - screen shots and all ;)

Answer (score 25):

For this particular problem (which usually comes with auto generated artifact files), I found a neat solution.

So if the issue is that your package declarations is "package abc;"  in 200 files, and you want it to be "package com.aa.bb.cc.abc;"

Then in eclipse, Search->File for "package abc;" in required folder or pkg or whole workspace. Don't select Search option but select "Replace" and then put "package com.aa.bb.cc.abc;" when it asks for the replacement after search.
Should do the trick.

Comment: Awesome! I've used Eclipse for 7 years but never seen 'Replace...' button.

Answer (score 7):

Right click on the package, select Refactor > Rename. This will update all source files with the new package name.

Comment: This doesn't work, it requires you to rename the packages. I don't want to rename or move them, I just need the "package blah.blah.blah in the source code to be updated to the right package folder.

Comment: @Stephane, Refactoring isn't working because refactoring doesn't fix your errors, it maneuvers code without errors to be structured differently.  You should move the new package to an empty project location, refactor it to match your used blah.blah.blah package imported in your source, move it back with your source, and then you can refactor the way you want to.

Comment: This worked for me because I did it after I renamed the package, then went to windows operating system and renamed the folder, then came back to eclipse and rename>refactor.

Comment: It worked for me rename it and do a rename again if you dont want to change the package name

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem so I wrote a bash script to do it.

```
function java-package-update { 
  for path in $(find $1 -type f -name "*.java"); do 
    D=$(dirname $path); 
    F=$(basename $path); 
    P=$(echo $D|tr '/' '.'); 
    if egrep -q '^\s*package\s*' $path; then 
      sed -i '' '/^\s*package\s*/s/^\(\s*package\s*\)[^;]*\(;.*\)/\1 '$P'\2/' $path; 
    else 
      echo >&2 "no package in $path";
    fi; 
  done; 
}
```

The `sed` command used is the one on OSX. If you're using gnu sed, then you don't need the '' paramater after the `-i`.

Just paste it in and run it on the directory containing your source. Backup your source first unless you're very brave.

Example:

```
$ cd /home/me/proj/fred/src
$ ls
com
$ cp -a com com.backup
$ java-package-update com
$ # fingers crossed
$ diff -ru com.backup com
```

I really should start doing this stuff in a more modern language like perl :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you.

Import all your files into the default package first and then drag them into
the new package, JDT will do the refactoring and change the package declarations across the project.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question, but I ran into the same problem and wrote a very simple bash script. Hope it will help someone.

```
for i in *.java; do
    sed -i 's/.*package com.example.something;.*/package com.example.something_else;/' $i
done
```

Basically, the script traverses all java files inside a directory, and each occurrence of `package com.example.something;` replaces with `package com.example.something_else;`.

Answer (score 0):

- `ALT+SHIFT+R` add underscore at end of package name, hit `ENTER` twice
- `ALT+SHIFT+R` delete the underscore, `ENTER` twice

Done if there are few packages.