# How to batch fix Java package in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, package

I have downloaded some Java source code from a book.
It contains many directories and many `.java` files in each of them.
How can I quickly fix the warning:

```
the declared package does not match the expected package "16.16-2"?
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6865694/617996)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Point your cursor to wrong declared package name (in editor or in problem view) and press <kbd>Ctrl+1</kbd>. That way Eclipse will offer you suggested package name which you can choose.

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6866062/617996) you can find more verbose explanation of answer on same question...

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse: Search -> Search -> File Search(Tab) -> Containing text(input your package) -> Replace -> Replace old package name with the new one