# How do I autofix "The declared package does not match..." errors in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a number of Java files in Eclipse that currently have the wrong package at the top of them. They are in the correct directory, however. I would like to fix all of the errors at once (read: not manually).

I have tried the following:

- If I go to the Problems view and try to Quick Fix, I can only do one
  at a time. If I select some subset and try to quick fix (all with the
  "The declared package" error), it states that they have nothing in
  common.
- I have also tried to use Source -> Clean Up but it doesn't fix my
  errors either.
- My last hope is Search and Replace, but I would really like something
  a bit more automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an answer here:

[Eclipse - How to "Change package declaration to ...." across an entire project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865694/eclipse-how-to-change-package-declaration-to-across-an-entire-project)

And to quote from the answer:

"Unfortunately there is no option to fix the issue across multiple units at one go; you will have to apply the quick fix for every problem."

Comment: Thank you. It's a shame about not being able to do it en masse, though.